How to apply normalization to a cross-correlation for a stream of complex data
I want to use this algorithm to get the Rxy correlation of a stream of complex data:
Rxy(x,y) = ifft(fft(x,N).*fft(flip(conj(y)),N);

I have a template (y) and I prepared it in this way for correlation:
s = generate_sequence(seq_id); % BPSK 1,-1s vector 
s_t = ifft(s);
y_t = resample(s_t,p,q);  % p and q fraction based on sample frequency Fs of (x_t) input data. 
x_t = get_input_data('file_name'); % complex int16 input data from a big binary file.

I calculated the block size and the number of blocks that I need to integrate in time based on the BW of my (y) template and the input data size; knowing that N = L + M -1 where N is my FFT size, M is my template size and L block size, to be used for the overlap-add.
y = fft(fliplr(conj(y_t)),N); % this is based on the FFT properties to have Rxy in time domain.
sum_y_0 = sum(y.*conj(y)); % to be used for Normalization.

Finally , these are the for loops for the overlap-add and calculating Rxy and normalizing on the go:
...
% Through Blocks of data
for blk_num = 0:nblocks-1                 
    idx = (1:L) + blk_num * L;            % sliding through input data.
    x = fft(x_t(idx),N);            
    x_sqr = x(idx) .* conj(x(idx));  
    sum_x_0 = sum(x_sqr);                 % sum_x_0 to be used for normalization
    
    % Through Channels
    for nch = 1: num_chs                  
        Rxy = ifft(x .* y);               % getting the correlation
        sum_Rxy  = sum(Rxy);
        norm_Rxy = real(sum_Rxy/sqrt(sum_x_0 * sum_y_0));  % ISSUE: getting normalization BUT SOMETIMES > 1.
        ...
        % overlap-add and filling the frequency-time matrix with correlation values.
        circshift(y, ch_spacing);
        ... 
    end
...
end

The issue I am having is that norm_Rxy values are sometimes higher than 1, and I am not sure why,  I thought it was because of the fft and ifft normalization but it seems Matlab is  taking care of it, if I do ifft(fft(vector)); I get the same vector values.
